# Derive frequency equations from an active multi feedback bandpass filter

Tags: frequency, formula-derivation, band-pass

I recently got some help deriving the transfer function of a multi feedback active bandpass filter made from capacitors resistors and an opamp working as an inverting amplifier.

The transfer function is if C1 and C2 are equal:

[image]

We have been given these formulas to calculate certain parameters:
[image]

and bandwidth: B = F_upper-F_lower = 1/(Pi*R3*C)

So my question is; how do I go from the transfer function into deriving these equations?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the denominator into standard form: -

\$s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_0 s + \omega_0^2\$

So divide through by \$C^2R_1R_2R_3\$ and the term that represents \$\omega_0^2\$ is:

\$\dfrac{R_1+R_2}{C^2R_1R_2R_3}\$

Therefore \$\omega_0\$ is \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{C^2R_3 (R_1 ||R_2)}}\$

At resonance, \$s^2\$ and \$\omega_0\$ cancel out so can you proceed with the final part now that you know that?

Comment: I don't understand the equation with omega_0, is it a general formula? The lattere formula you derived is still missing 2pi. The reason I'm asking is because I want to know why you do these things and how.

Is there somewhere I can read about it?

Comment: Knowing that the damping factor is ζ=1/2Q and the bandwidth is B=fo/Q, we can find that the bandwidth is B=1/(Pi*R3*C).

Comment: @dnopas the \$2\pi\$ is missing because omega is in radians per second as opposed to hertz. The standard formula for a 2nd order filter is etched in stone and try googling it like here: https://www.google.com/search?q=standard+transfer+function+for+a+2nd+order+filter&client=firefox-b&biw=1293&bih=902&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid3o6Qvf_MAhUHrxoKHVhxDEsQsAQISw follow the links in the pictures.

Comment: But why is w0^2 not sqrt of (r1+r2)/(C^2R3(R1||R2)). It's like something is missing, like you take the inverse of the w0^2 value before squarerooting it?

I found the bandpass formular which is (a*s)/(s^2+omega_0/Q+omega_0^2)

Comment: And right now I have the (R1+R2)/(C^2R1R2R3) in the denominator, which means the squareroot of that is my w_0, but it's not supposed to be, C^2 and R2 need to be in the numerator of the w_0^2 factor

Comment: @dnopas I have no idea what the last part of your latest comment meant. Are you saying there is something you don't understand about the "||" bit?

Answer (score 0):

Replace \$s\$ with \$j2\pi f\$. If \$f_0\$ is the cut-off frequency then it may be found by equating the real and imaginary parts of the transfer function.If \$f_0\$ is the resonant frequency then it is the one when imaginary part of the transfer function equals zero.